# How to enable Puppeteer generate PDFs that correctly reflect screen @media queries

Tags: node.js, pdf, media-queries, puppeteer, chromium

Screen Media Queries are not applied correctly in the generated PDF file.
It appears that Chrome ignores (or mismatches it somehow) the provided page width when processing screen @media queries.
Puppeteer version 21.1.1

Here is what i tried:

```
const browser = await puppeteer.launch({
  args: ['--no-sandbox'],
  headless: "new"
});
const page = await browser.newPage();
await page.setContent(content,{waitUntil:'networkidle0'});
await page.emulateMediaType('screen');
const pdfBuffer = await page.pdf({
  width: '1400px',
  height: '900px',
  printBackground: true
});
```

It also seems that setting a viewport has no effect on PDF rendering at all:

```
await page.setViewport({
  width: 1400,
  height: 900,
  deviceScaleFactor: 1
});
```

Here is what css i have in `content`:

```
@media (min-width: 1250px) { /* will work only if i change it into 1050px */
  .container {
    max-width: 540px;
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Issue has been fixed in chrome 117 version.